# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Error

Tags: sql-server, dll

I installed SSMS 2017.

When I run it, I can connect to a server successfully in Object Explorer.

But when I try to open New Query `(File - New - Query with Current Connection)`, I get the following error:

> Error loading type library/DLL.
>       (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

The same error I get when I try to open .sql file.

Please help me solve this problem.

P.S. Does anyone know how to get more detailed information about this error? Maybe there is somewhere an error log.

Answer (score 0):

[**Sorce**](http://vasudevtroubleshooting.blogspot.in/2009/09/sql-server-management-studio-to-ssis.html)

**Cause:**

> During each service pack setup, we unregister the older versions of
>   these  DLLs (along with a lot of others), copy the new ones and
>   re-register them. The  registering phase may have failed on these
>   files. The installation log of the  service pack can confirm us that.

**Solution:**

> We Need to Un-Register both 32Bit and 64Bit of Dts.dll and Un-Register
>   both  32Bit and 64Bit of MsDtsSrvrUtil.dll and Re-Register both 32Bit
>   and 64Bit of  Dts.dll and both 32Bit and 64Bit of MsDtsSrvrUtil.dll

Comment: This didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and solved it following instructions from microsoft site
[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2416767/you-may-get-an-error-message-when-trying-to-load-or-save-a-ssis-packag)

It basically says:

> Run the following commands in Administrative Command prompt
>
> **On a 32-bit machine:**
>
> `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\msxml6.dll`
>
> `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\msxml3.dll`
>
> **On a 64-bit system, reregister both the 32-bit and 64-bit Dlls:**
>
> `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\msxml6.dll`
>
> `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\msxml3.dll`
>
> `regsvr32 %windir%\SysWOW64\msxml3.dll`
>
> `regsvr32 %windir%\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll`